# How to Add Google map in Samsung galaxy tab

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried to adding the google map thing in my application, And my application for Samsung galaxy.I tried it using two ways, but still I failed.

**One Way** : copying the system.img from android-sdk\windows\add-ons
\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\images to android-sdk\windows\add-ons
\addon_galaxy_tab_samsung_electronics_8\images , overwriting the one
that was there, and then creating a new AVD.

**Anotherway** :

copy (android sdk)/add-ons/(galaxy target/skins/. to (android sdk)/add-ons/(google target)

edit the manifest file in the directory for (google target)

add "skin=GALAXY Tab" (without quotes) to the manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second ways works fine. I created another appplication and then use the second way i.e

copy (android sdk)/add-ons/(galaxy target/skins/. to (android sdk)/add-ons/(google target)

edit the manifest file in the directory for (google target)

add "skin=GALAXY Tab" (without quotes) to the manifest file.

Comment: But whats the point of that? Its just a normal emulator that looks like a tab. Just for screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

Another way

copy the folder
"GALAXY Tab"
from `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-galaxy_tab-samsung_electronics-8\skins`

then paste it to

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\skins
```

then create a new AVD with the target platform but choose Galaxy tab as a skin